# BASH script that generates a header file with function prototypes

Tags: linux, bash, bash-scripting, c

I am doing a C project which involves lots of static linking.

To get rid of "implict function declaration" errors I will use a simple solution - a header file with function prototypes.

I wrote this script:

```
#!/bin/bash
for file_to_parse in `find -type f -name "*.c"`; do
    cproto $file_to_parse > proto.h 2> /dev/null
done
```

It should create a file called `proto.h` and store function prototypes there.

Notes:

`find -type f -name "*.c"` this command returns the pathnames of all c files in the directory of this script.

eg `./folder1/file1.c`

`cproto <i>file</i>` => this creates function prototypes from functions found in `file`.

eg `<code>double myfunction(int a,char b);`

Problem:

The code generates an empty file.

What is wrong with this bash script?

Comment: So what is your question?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20180734/are-function-prototypes-needed-in-header-files

Answer (score 3):

There are surely many ways to change it. Here is but one:

```
 #!/bin/bash
 if [ ! -f proto.h ]; then
       touch proto.h
 fi
 for file_to_parse in `find -type f -name "*.c"`; do
    cproto $file_to_parse >> proto.h 2> /dev/null
 done
```

The error is in the redirection in the `cproto...` line: the simple `>` first wipes the destination file, then writes into it. Instead, `>>` *appends* to the destination file without destroying it. The `if` loop is there just to make sure that at the first pass you will not be appending to a non-existent file: there is nothing wrong with appending to a non-existent file, no error is thrown; it's just that I like to make sure it is a simple, **regular** file, before writing to it.